# How to switch Quiescing to Normal Mode in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, replication

I have two instance database Oracle, they are ORCL11 and ORCL10,.... I've configured them, it looks like correct. Then, I connect to replication user admin ORCL10

```
conn repadmin/repadmin@orcl10
```

And run SQL command in replication admin user ORCL10,...

```
BEGIN DBMS_REPCAT.RESUME_MASTER_ACTIVITY (gname=>'scott_repg');end;/
```

Then, i connect to replication admin user ORCL11 to see gname status.

```
conn repadmin/repadmin@orcl11;
select gname,status from dba_repgroup;
```

It display gname = SCOTT_REPG and status = NORMAL,.... but if connect to replication admin ORCL10

```
conn repadmin/repadmin@orcl10;
select gname,status from dba_repgroup;
```

It display that gname = SCOTT_REPG and STATUS = QUIESCING, I think it does not have any impact, so I test my replication on ORCL10, for example :

```
conn system/ok@orcl10;
insert into DEPT values (101,'Financial');
select*from DEPT;
```

It works on table DEPT ORCL10 (1 row created), but when i switch to ORCL11 then run simple sql query :

```
conn system/ok@orcl11;
select*from DEPT;
```

it doesn't show anything, i've searched it on Google but there is nothing tutorial how to fix that, I think the problem is about how to switch QUIESCING to NORMAL mode at ORCL10. I've try this way to fix it :

```
ALTER SYSTEM QUIESCE RESTRICTED;
ALTER SYSTEM UNQUIESCE;
```

But it still doesn't solve the problem,..... Would you help me to fix this problem ??? thanks !!!

Comment: Did you issue a `COMMIT`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've done it,.... COMMIT, but it still no change in ORCL11 ??? any the other idea ???

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up quiescing a replication master group and quiescing a database — these are different concepts:

1. [ALTER SYSTEM QUIESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_2014.htm#SQLRF53132)

   > Use the QUIESCE RESTRICTED and UNQUIESCE clauses to put the database in and take it out of the quiesced state. This state enables database administrators to perform administrative operations that cannot be safely performed in the presence of concurrent transactions, queries, or PL/SQL operations.
2. [Master Group Quiesce](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10706/repoverview.htm#sthref33)

   > At times, you must stop all replication activity for a master group so that you can perform certain administrative tasks on the master group. For example, you must stop all replication activity for a master group to add a new master group object. Stopping all replication activity for a master group is called quiescing the group. When a master group is quiesced, users cannot issue DML statements on any of the objects in the master group. Also, all deferred transactions must be propagated before you can quiesce a master group. Users can continue to query the tables in a quiesced master group.

After quiescing a replication master group, [RESUME_MASTER_ACTIVITY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28327/rarrcatpac.htm#i98814) resumes normal replication activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following.

`Connect as repadmin/password@SID`

`SQL>EXECUTE Dbms_Repcat.Resume_Master_Activity(gname => 'MYREPGRP');`
Replace MYREPGRP with your gname which can be obtained from

`select gname from dba_repsites`

After running DBMS_Repcat, you should issue commit. It should be done.

Answer (score -1):

alter system enable restricted session;

Comment: This may answer the question (I don't know) but you are unlikely to get up-votes from the community unless you [edit] this answer to provide some explanation: Why does this work? Link to documentation? And so on.